# preventing db locks in sqlite tcl

Tags: database, sqlite, tcl, locks

I hav an TCL application where multiple children read and write from a single DB connection to a sqlite DB and as sone of the child processes can take longer than the others,I encounter "database locked" error thrown by TCL.

I know I can have busy call back method with TCL API for sqlite - but it does not seem to be called even when the db is locked. I just want all children to work properly and make any children wait for the lock and retry.

any advice/examples much appreciated.

thanks

Comment: Technically, that error comes from SQLite (or at least the Tcl interface to it) and not from Tcl itself.

Answer (score 1):

Looking through [the documentation](https://sqlite.org/tclsqlite.html), I see that:

```
dbconn timeout 2000
```

will set the lock-acquisition timeout to 2 seconds. Or you can tinker with the `busy` method. How long it *should* be seems to depend on how much contention you've got going on (a factor that has to be tuned according to your hardware and code deployment) and also whether SQLite's been compiled with support for short sleeping (if `HAVE_USLEEP` wasn't `1` during configuration, [bad things can happen](http://beets.radbox.org/blog/sqlite-nightmare.html) apparently). If you've got such a dodgy build in play, I *strongly* recommend fixing that because you don't know what else is mis-configured.

Comment: hi thanks for that..but the busy method is not called..thats the problem..have you got any working code examples I can look at ?